# Mac recognizes usb installer, but instead of booting into it, it boots from internal hdd

Tags: restore, bootable-disk

I've used this usb drive in the past to restore macs and I don't remember what I did to get it to work. I get into the drive selection for booting, the usb with high sierra installer is there, but upon selecting it, it just boots from internal hdd. I remember having to use the command-line in the past due to expired certificate issues, but my goldfish brain can't remember what I did and I can't seem to find anything on Google. What am I missing here?

Comment: Try using single-user mode (nvram boot-args="-s") and see what is the output.

Comment: The certificate is characterized by a message about the installer not being verifiable or words to that effect. That silent refusal to boot may just be a damaged installer USB drive. Have you tried re-creating it?

Comment: This happens to me.  I find it best to power off your computer and all accessories.  I have all l my devices connected to two power strips.  I power off both power strips.

Comment: I gave up and used internet recovery. I'll make a new bootable usb in the future.Thanks for all your help!